# firefox js getSVGDocument().getElementsByClassName('myClass') broken?

Tags: firefox, svg, getelementsbyclassname

i have an embedded SVG, using js to change 20 path fill colors, all having the same class.

```
<script>
function svgMod(){  
    //var links = document.getElementById("tornado5").getSVGDocument().
    //    getElementsByClassName('SVGlogo');
    var links = document.getElementById("tornado5").contentDocument.
        getElementsByClassName('SVGlogo');

    for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) { links[i].style.fill="00ff00"; }  
}
</script>
<object type="image/svg+xml" id="tornado5" data="bitmaps/frames/tornado2.svg">
</object>        <!-- cant use img -->
<button onclick="svgMod();" >Click to change</button>
```

It works in Chrome, but not firefox.
ive tried both contentDocument and getSVGDocument(), but no help.  links.length is 20, even in firefox, so the problem seems to be in links[i].style.fill

any ideas?

Comment: As Tanzeel Kazi says, the problem is that your value for "fill" is not valid CSS.  A valid value would be `#00ff00`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing this line:

```
for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) { links[i].style.fill="00ff00"; }
```

to this:

```
for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].setAttribute("fill", "#00ff00");
}
```

OR

```
for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].style.fill = "#00ff00";
}
```

Hope this helps.